# How to setup proxy in flutter web to load a url in iframe?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to add

```
proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;
proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
```

in proxy config to load a URL in iframe. But I didn't set up any proxy config in my flutter web application.
I have no idea about how to set up and where I add this policy. I search but didn't get any expected results.

Below is the  code of iframe,

```
final IFrameElement _iFrameElement = IFrameElement();
  @override
  void initState() {

    _iFrameElement.style.height = '80%';
    _iFrameElement.style.width = '80%';
    _iFrameElement.src = url;
    _iFrameElement.style.border = 'none';
// ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
          (int viewId) => _iFrameElement,
    );

    super.initState();
  }
  final Widget _iframeWidget = HtmlElementView(
    viewType: 'iframeElement',
    key: UniqueKey(),
  );

 SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: _iframeWidget,
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  var client = http.Client();
  var response = await client.get(
    'https://www.example.com',
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentSecurityPolicyHeader: "",
      HttpHeaders.xFrameOptionsHeader: "",
    },
    proxy: new Proxy.fromJson({
      'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:8080',
      'https': 'https://proxy.example.com:8080',
    }),
  );

  print(response.body);
}
```

Comment: i have a url to load in inframe..To load that URL I need to add proxy.so is it possible to add proxy in that case?

Comment: yes. possible . did you try?

Comment: i didn't see any option to add a proxy in an iframe. Could you please give an example? It would be really helpful if you share a sample.

Comment: contentSecurityPolicyHeader is not listing in httpheaders.HttpHeaders.contentSecurityPolicyHeader: "", contentSecuritityPolicy shows an error

Comment: Did you try web view?